# Windows Service Fails due to Kernelbase.dll error

Tags: windows, service, kernel

I have an issue with a Windows Service that crashes every 'now and then'.
The error I get is

> Blockquote
>   Faulting application name: wsCSV.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x53ce2a27
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1116
>   Exception code: 0xe053534f
>   Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
>   Faulting process id: 0x%9
>   Faulting application start time: 0x%10
>   Faulting application path: %11
>   Faulting module path: %12
>   Report Id: %13

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-07-27T06:51:27.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3250</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>ComputerName.Domain.com</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>wsCSV.exe</Data> 
  <Data>1.0.0.0</Data> 
  <Data>53ce2a27</Data> 
  <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
  <Data>6.1.7601.18229</Data> 
  <Data>51fb1116</Data> 
  <Data>e053534f</Data> 
  <Data>0000c41f</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I am unable to write to the event log because our IT Security have locked it down and don't know how to unlock it so am writing a text file to show if I have any errors in the application that I can handle.

but this is generated in the Windows Logs under the Application Node.

What I need to understand is what could be the cause of this. I suspect it could be because the machine is locked down that it causes the issue, however the one thing that blows this out of the water is that its not a consistent issue.

Any and all help would be awesome thanks

Simon

Comment: Probably an application bug. Memory corruption.

Comment: I thought this, but have been running is successfully on my machine for days without an instance of any failure.... 

with it being in the kernel I am looking at a way to build a resource monitor for it if I can